# Rails 3 - Redirect_to / Render another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 2 controllers: `Projects` and `Users`. Both models have no relation at all.

When I create a new `Project` I want to redirect to the `new User path` after saving the new `project`, but all my tries give erros like missing template or stuff like that.

How can I get this working?

**EDITED**

My create method in `Projects` controller:

def create

@project = Project.new(params[:project])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save     
    format.html { render (new_user_registration_path) }

  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying to use?

Comment: Add the stacktrace to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to render new_user_registration_path, you want to redirect_to new_user_registration_path

Answer (score 0):

you must use redirect_to instead render:

```
 redirect_to new_user_registration_path

 respond_to do |format|
   if @project.save     
     format.html { redirect_to new_user_registration_path }
   else
     format.html { render :action => "new" }
     format.xml  { render :xml => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
```